# TF 2.2 Saved_model from keras with custom signatures and preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to use the `tf.saved_model.save` after a training a Transformer Model in order to deploy it.
My model has multiple inputs and outputs. If I am using the saved_model function for serving, I add some issue about the input shape with the first input, and the second input is not visible when I am using the `saved_model_cli show` function. I found a way to solve that issue by wrapping the main transformer block by a model module and then save the model.

```
def build_model(MAX_LEN, transformer_layer):
    inp = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    inp2 = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_mask")
    sequence_output, pooled_output = transformer_layer(inp, attention_mask = inp2)
    out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='outputs')(pooled_output)
    model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out])
    return model
```

But, I see in the documentation there is another way which consist in using signatures to indicate the inputs/outputs during the  `tf.saved_model.save`. To do that, we need to use the `tf.Module` class but I haven't understood how to use it in the case we have multiple inputs/outputs exactly (how to make understand the module that inputs tensor should be related to that inputs for the model?) .
Does anyone know how to do that with the second method ?  Morever can we do preprocessing of the data through the signature ?https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

```
class CustomModule(tf.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super(CustomModule, self).__init__()
    self.v = tf.Variable(1.)

  @tf.function
  def __call__(self, x):
    print('Tracing with', x)
    return x * self.v

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([], tf.float32)])
  def mutate(self, new_v):
    self.v.assign(new_v)

module = CustomModule()
```